# Placing $n$ zeroes between $5$ and $4$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, decimal-expansion

How much does the number $542$ increase when we merge $ n $ zeros between $ 5 $ and $ 4 $?

I found it out $500\cdot99...9$ (''n'' noves) units

[exemple: $500\cdot9+542=5042$]

But how do I prove it?

Comment: Please do not use periods for multiplication.  $500.9$ looks like $500\frac 9{10}$.  Use \cdot instead to get a centered dot.  Also to get an ellipsis (three lower dots) you can use \ldots

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original number is $5\cdot 10^2+42$.  If you put in $n$ zeros you get $5 \cdot 10^{2+n}+42$.  The difference of these is $5 \cdot (10^{2+n}-10^2)=5\cdot 10^2\cdot (10^n-1)$ and the last number consists of $n\ 9$s